# Adding vuetify to my project with Require JS?

Tags: vue.js, requirejs, vuetify.js

I tried to add vuetify to my existing project with require.js and got this error:

TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.extend is not a function

I added vue.js itself and worked without any error. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is it compulsory to use requirejs ?

If you can use another method, don't forget to check this one :

> Go in your vue file
>
> `$ cd ./myVueFile/`
>
> Then use Vue CLI to install Vuetify
>
> `$ vue add vuetify`

I extracted that from the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/), they have great explanations on how to install Vuetify, plus they provide a thorough documentation on how to use their components !

Comment: Yes, I should use require.js, I think the problem was naming Vue or vue in my require.config.js. I'm trying to fix it...